# Log message after obfuscating

Tags: java, logging, obfuscation, proguard

I had a java-based product and obfuscated it before releasing, but there are log messages at each method. I understand that the log message may be used to track down the code and use reverse-engineering to reverse the code, but it's useful to track down the error in case something wrong happens.

**My question is:** Should I keep the log message after obfuscating? If not, is there any other way to track down the error in case something happens wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you change your mind-set.  If you obfuscate the code, you will prevent a casual "reverse engineer" from understanding it.  However, you will probably have little effect on someone who's determined to decipher the code, and you will make your own job much harder when it's time to reproduce a subtle bug using only a field report.

I suggest you do some experiments to evaluate the extra cost of debugging and maintenance (and customer irritation when you can't quickly resolve a problem) vs the value of the intellectual property, the likelihood anybody will actually *want* to reverse engineer it, and the cost you will incur if someone does reverse engineer parts of your system.

Comment: +1 - Obfuscation is a pain in the backside for host customers.  Which is more important to you / your business - stopping non-paying customers from using your code or no alienating your paying customers?  Hint: when I encounter obfuscated code, I immediately start looking for an alternative vendor.

Comment: @StephenC: to be clear, I suppose you've missed s.t. Generally, I sell my product excluding source code, and the price is calculate for that. If I intend to sell my product including source code, the price will be much higher than it should be. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Thinhbk - I generally develop and use open source software LARGELY because of the problems I've had with expensive closed source products that don't work properly.  My attitude is that if I pay good money for a product, it either has to be pretty damn good, or I want source code for free.  I am not going to pay lots of extra money for the "privilege" of finding and fixing bugs in your code.

Comment: @Thinhbk - and I forgot to mention that obfuscated code is going to make my life hell if I ever need to figure out why your code isn't working as expected.  As a paying customer I don't need that problem.  I want to be treated with respect, not as a potential IP thief.

Comment: @StephenC: I agree that the customers must be treated with respect; but in some case, the customer is also your competitor. What should I treat with this kind of customer?